# loop through all charts and change the label format vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to loop through all charts in an excel and change all the labels format to integer. here is my code:

```
Sub LoopThroughCharts()

Dim sht As Worksheet

Dim CurrentSheet As Worksheet

Dim cht As ChartObject

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Set CurrentSheet = ActiveSheet

  For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each cht In sht.ChartObjects
      cht.Activate
      cht.chart.FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.NumberFormat = "#,##0"

  Next cht
Next sht

CurrentSheet.Activate
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

However, I cannot run it. 
The error given to me is Run-time error

> '-2147467259(80004005)': Unable to get the Count property of the
>   DataLabels class

Also, the code works fine on single chart. Could someone help with the issue please?

Comment: 1. Not `FullSeriesCollection`, but `SeriesCollection`. 2. Don't see `Count` in your code. 3. There's no need to activate chart.

Comment: 4. Why do you say that code works for a single chart? Perhaps, you mean for a single series?

Comment: Hey JohnyL, thank you very much for the help. I actually wrote the code without Loop first, and it actually worked and changed the format of all the datalabels of a chart. After add a loop, it showed the error. The error is that for some of the charts, not all series are labelled. By the way, It seems i do not need to count (point2)

Comment: I answered you.

Answer (score 0):

You will get that error only if the data labels are not set for a chart and you try to change the format of the data labels.

Try it like this...

```
For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each cht In sht.ChartObjects
        cht.Chart.SetElement msoElementDataLabelOutSideEnd
        cht.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.NumberFormat = "#,##0"
    Next cht
Next sht
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment! I figured that some of the series are not labeled and that was the error. I also tried the code you provided, it showed a different error " Method 'SetElement' of object "_Chart' failed "

Comment: By the way, would mind explaining a bit of the " cht.Chart.SetElement msoElementDataLabelOutSideEnd" ? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: You're welcome! That line enables the data labels and their position.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check `HasDataLabels` property of *each* series (non-relevant code is removed):

```
Sub LoopThroughCharts()

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim cht As ChartObject
    Dim ser As Series

    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each cht In sht.ChartObjects
            For Each ser In cht.Chart.SeriesCollection
                If ser.HasDataLabels Then
                    ser.DataLabels.NumberFormat = "#,##0"
                End If
            Next
        Next cht
    Next sht

End Sub
```